# shutil.copyfileobj incorrectly copied data

Tags: python

In order to work with some picture (download it, detect format and store) I use the following code:

```
image = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url)
buf = io.BytesIO()
shutil.copyfileobj(image, buf)
ext = imghdr.what(buf)
```

And ext was empty (meaning format could not be detected). I tried redoing it a bit differently:

```
image = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
test = image.read()
binbuf = io.BytesIO(test)
imghdr.what(binbuf)
```

And this actually worked. My conclusion is that copyfileobj messes thing up somehow. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you write to `buf` with `shutil.copyfileobj(image, buf)`, `buf`'s stream pointer is pointing at the next position after the end of the data you just wrote. When you try to do `ext = imghdr.what(buf)`, it reads nothing (because there's nothing more to read from that position) and returns `None`. You need to `.seek()` back to `0` before trying to read what you just wrote.

This works:

```
image = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url)
buf = io.BytesIO()
shutil.copyfileobj(image, buf)
buf.seek(0)
ext = imghdr.what(buf)
```